# PHP Array always returning null

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm just using a single-dimension array, nothing special

```
$invalid_custom_transaction_ids = array();
```

**Method 1:**

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($row['TransactionID'] == $paypal_transaction_id) {
        error_log("[DIE]1");
        die();
    }
    error_log("[PUSHING]".$row['CustomTransID']);
    array_push($invalid_custom_transaction_ids, $row['CustomTransID']);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($row['TransactionID'] == $paypal_transaction_id) {
        error_log("[DIE]1");
        die();
    }
    error_log("[PUSHING]".$row['CustomTransID']);
    $invalid_custom_transaction_ids[] = $row['CustomTransID'];
}
```

The following is printed to the debug log, showing that there are values that I've tried adding to the array()

> [03-Nov-2014 08:48:25 America/Los_Angeles] [PUSHING]Ux837Yn3rK3

When I try to print the array to the debug_log using the following code

```
    error_log(var_dump($invalid_custom_transaction_ids));
```

it returns blank, I've also tried this

```
    error_log(array_values($invalid_custom_transaction_ids));
```

Output to the error_log file looks like this:

> [03-Nov-2014 08:48:25 America/Los_Angeles]

Then the following error is printed

> [03-Nov-2014 08:48:25 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /path/to/script.php on line 195

The code that is on line 195 is as follow:

```
function uniqueTransactionCheck() {
    error_log("[UTC]1");
    error_log(var_dump($invalid_custom_transaction_ids));
    error_log("Is array: " . is_array($invalid_custom_transaction_ids));
    foreach($invalid_custom_transaction_ids as $invalid) {
        if($custom_transaction_id == $invalid) {
            $custom_transaction_id = generateTransactionID();
            uniqueTransactionCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

What's the deal? I don't understand this at all, I've been trying and trying to get this right, and shuffling through different documentaries and methods. I'm absolutely flabbergasted.

---

-snip-

Comment: Maybe the `$invalid_custom_transactions_ids` is empty, and therefor the `foreach()` will throw that error... Try to `var_dump()` it and `die()` to see if you have something in it for sure...

Comment: It would really be better to see your code as-is, rather than broken apart into pieces where we don't know the relation between one piece and another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that `var_dump` does not return a string. It prints to standard output. When you write `error_log(var_dump(...))` it is not writing the var_dump output to your error log.

It looks to me that the type of the variable is not an array as you expect. Can you print out the result of `is_array($invalid_custom_transaction_ids)`?

EDIT:

Ok so your issue is that in `uniqueTransactionCheck()` you are referencing a variable called `$invalid_custom_transaction_ids`.

However, that variable does not exist in the scope of `uniqueTransactionCheck()`. You probably want to pass the variable as an argument. If you run the following code in `uniqueTransactionCheck()` you will see false printed in your logs:

`error_log(isset($invalid_custom_transaction_ids))`

Comment: Does `error_log(array_values($invalid_custom_transaction_ids));` also not return anything? Either way, this doesn't explain why the `foreach()` is refusing to handle the array

Comment: @Christian.tucker Obviously it is not an array.

Comment: `$invalid_custom_transaction_ids = array();` and `array_push($invalid_custom_transaction_ids, $row['CustomTransID']);`.. so it's `obviously` supposed to be one.

Comment: @Christian.tucker See my edit. `$invalid_custom_transaction_ids` is not an array in the function you are getting the error.

Comment: [03-Nov-2014 09:08:50 America/Los_Angeles] Is array: -- The results of `is_array($invalid_custom_transaction_ids)` return blank.

Comment: Oh wow, Thank you. I'm not used to the scoping of PHP, usually variables are accessable to the entire class in other languages, so it's really thrown me for a loop, thanks again.